# How to get text out of a delimited string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract a portion of a delimited string. The string is something like this:

272;#This is the text i want

I'd like to get everything after the "#". Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=#).*
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Language implementations matter. Not all languages support every regular expression operator or feature. There are some general approaches, though, such as zero-width assertions and capture groups.

#### Positive Lookbehind

Use a zero-width assertion to find the character preceding your string. For example, to capture just the text of interest using Ruby 2.0:

```
'272;#This is the text i want'.match /(?<=#).*/
pp $&
#=> "This is the text i want"
```

#### Capture Groups

Use capture and non-capture groups to match text, then extract the group you're interested in. For example, to capture your desired match in the first capturing group with Ruby 2.0:

```
'272;#This is the text i want'.match /(?:#)(.*)/
pp $1
#=> "This is the text i want"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex `#(.*)` and extract the first capturing group - btw, what language are you trying to do this??

edit: if you can't access the capturing groups you can try lookbehind if it's supported by the engine:

```
(?<=#).*
```

Comment: SharePoint 2010 Nintex Workflow

Comment: tried it and i get the "#" at the beginning as well as the end text. is there an easy way to omit that?

ie. #This is the text i want

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string text = "272;#";
int index = text.IndexOf("#");
string sub = text.Substring(index + 1);
```